# Print Visual, Pagination , MVVM Pattern.

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mvvm, pagination

Im trying to print visual (or anything related) with pagination from a WPF element. I'm using a MVVM Pattern development.

This is my visual layout. Where the user can scroll to view the pages.

```
  <ScrollViewer>
          <StackPanel x:Name="Wrapper">
              <StackPanel x:Name="PageOne" />
              <StackPanel x:Name="PageTwo" />
          </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

The visual is passed via a Command Binding on a button.

```
 <Button Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{BindingElementName=Wrapper}"
```

The visual is passed to the print Method.

```
PrintDialog newDialog = new PrintDialog();

newDialog.PrintVisual(MyVisualName, "Printing is Fun!");
```

I would like to paginate the two pages (and more), and also scale the visual to the paper, Whilst holding true to MVVM style.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i used Flow Inline Flowdocument.

```
 <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
            <FlowDocument x:Name="EntirePage">
                <Section>
                    <BlockUIContainer>
                    </BlockUIContainer>
                </Section>
            </FlowDocument>
 </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Every control within the BlockUIContainer is printed. (A Lot of page size and margin fiddling is required to get pagination working perfectly) *Section/ BlockUI does pagination somewhat automatically - so for me page one was one BlockUi and Page two was another - Comment/Ask for more info*

```
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EntirePage}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I passed the FlowDocument via a command Parameter.

```
          printCommand = new RelayCommand(p => PreparePrint((FlowDocument)p));
```

(pageVisual being the flow document passed via the command param)

Then between a few of methods i get to;

```
          IDocumentPaginatorSource idocument = pageVisual as IDocumentPaginatorSource;


          printDialog.PrintDocument(idocument.DocumentPaginator, "Printing Machine : " + Machine.Serial);
```

If you are confused and need help (much like i was) then don't hesitate to comment/ask questions.